# Drawing a scatterplot in Java

Tags: java, graphics

I came across this code and I have been playing around with it, however the points I tried to plot seem to be in the incorrect places. I want to be able to plot like a graph so the origin (0,0) should be in the bottom left corner and points should plotted relative to that, can some help me?

```
package graphtest;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.*;

public class Scatterplot extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private List points = new ArrayList();

    public Scatterplot() {
        super("Scatterplot");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        points.add(new Point2D.Float(1, 4));
        points.add(new Point2D.Float(2, 10));
        points.add(new Point2D.Float(3, 12));
        //points.add(new Point2D.Float(3, 10));
       // points.add(new Point2D.Float(4, 12));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {  
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                //g.translate(0, 0);
                for(Iterator i=points.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                    Point2D.Float pt = (Point2D.Float)i.next();
                    g.drawString(".", (int)pt.x, (int)pt.y);
                }

            }
        };

        setContentPane(panel);
        setBounds(10, 10, 200, 200);

        setVisible(true);       
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Scatterplot();
    }
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Start by making sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` before doing any drawing.  Coordinates will relative to the component they are been painted in, not the frame...

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problems you've gotten yourself into (apart from not understand what the code is trying to do), is...

1. Not calling `super.paintComponent` first, before doing any custom painting
2. Using `drawString`...

Using `drawString` to draw a `.` character means that the dot will appear well below the `y` position you specify, as the character has to take into consideration the overall height of all the characters that make up the font.  Fonts also render about there ascent line, this can also throw the `y` position off as well.

Instead, you should make better use of the `Graphics2D` API and actually paint the dot, for example...

This example basically uses a `Ellipse2D` to draw the dots, I've set it up so that it will paint the centre of dot at the specified x/y coordinates.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Scatterplot extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private List points = new ArrayList();

    public Scatterplot() {
        super("Scatterplot");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        points.add(new Point2D.Float(1, 4));
        points.add(new Point2D.Float(2, 10));
        points.add(new Point2D.Float(3, 12));
        //points.add(new Point2D.Float(3, 10));
        // points.add(new Point2D.Float(4, 12));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                //g.translate(0, 0);
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
//                g.setColor(Color.RED);
//                g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                for (Iterator i = points.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                    Point2D.Float pt = (Point2D.Float) i.next();
                    Ellipse2D dot = new Ellipse2D.Float(pt.x - 1, pt.y - 1, 2, 2);
                    g2d.fill(dot);
                }
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        };

        setContentPane(panel);
        setBounds(10, 10, 200, 200);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                new Scatterplot();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Take a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details